# HTML select element name value for accessability

Tags: html

Based on [accessability docs](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H91#example-6), `<select>` element can get a name by either providing a label:

```
<label for="selectEl"> Name of the select </label>
<select id="selectEl">
```

Or by adding a `title` attribute:

```
<select title="Name of the select">
```

Are there other options? Because both of these visually changes the view on screen (label displays label and title displays its value on mouse hover). So in order to add support for accessability, I must change how the `select` is displayed?

Is that `aria-label` attribute? Why then documentation doesn't mention it?

Comment: Worth reading: https://www.24a11y.com/2019/select-your-poison/

Comment: Thanks, thats a good one